# Impact on existing users if password length is changed in Amazon Cognito

Tags: amazon-cognito

We use Cognito as IDP. Currently password length policy is set to 6 and we has been asked to change it to 10.
If we do this change on Cognito, will it impact existing users. If 'yes' - how?